# Other ways of saying "Don't give up"?

Tags: idioms, synonyms, slang

In the context of "... but either way, don't give up on yourself yet..."

Perhaps

Don't bury yourself?

Don't put a cross on yourself?

I'm not native so it's hard for me to decide if any of these even make sense in English

Answer (score 4):

There are a few phrases you could try, some work better than others depending on the exact (fuller) context you use them in and the person to whom you're speaking/writing. You might consider:

- Hang in there
- Stick with it
- Don't jump ship just yet
- Give it some time
- Don't throw in the towel just yet
- Keep the faith a while longer

Comment: Those work but I need something a psychiatrist or a doctor could say to a patient who's desperate and doesn't believe in future treatment

Comment: Oof. That's a pretty specific case. Telling the patient to not give up would be a part of a deeper monologue. In this case, a doctor or psychiatrist might very well just say "Don't give up hope" but then fo on to give reasons why the patient should not give up hope as a way to help reassure.